Image on PDF Quote
I have an image field in QuoteLineItem and I want to show it in the Quote PDF, but the images look like this, does anyone know if it is possible to show an image in the Quote PDF


How are you generating the PDF? Is is a standard button that Salesforce provides, or are you using something like a Visualforce page and renderAsPDF in a custom button/action/link? If it's a custom Visualforce page, please include it in your question by making an [edit] (also, be sure to select your code and push the {} button so everything is rendered correctly. StackExchange won't render stuff that looks like HTML for safety reasons (unless it's formatted as a code block).

@DerekF is standard button

does the image field link to a Document that is externally visible?

yes, it is a formula field that takes the image from another formula field that is in the product object, the image is stored in Static Resources @DerekF

Did you follow the instructions in the doc?  The doc doesn't mention formula fields but instead you insert an image in the quote template editor
